# Extra capabilities shown in IAMStreamConfig::GetNumberOfCapabilities method (Directshow programming)

Tags: windows, video, camera, directshow, video-capture

Extra capabilities shown in 
**IAMStreamConfig::GetNumberOfCapabilities([out]  int *piCount,[out]  int *piSize )** method where,

**piCount** has the value double the actual supported formats.

---

for example I have 4 supported resolutions in 2 formats (YUV AND MJPEG) which makes 8 in total but my count value is 16.

While validating I found that there where duplicate capabilities of    FORMAT_VideoInfo2 type other than FORMAT_VideoInfo which was actually implemented.

---

Have anyone came across this issue or have an idea on why this duplication occurs ?

Comment: There is no issue. The duplication occurs exactly because the driver informs that both VIH and VIH2 are available. This duplication is not only allowed, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: My question is why the driver has to show VIH2 available while only VIH is implemented ? And if it is just showing the available format types why not show all the format types that can be implemented ?

Comment: There is no special need in VIH2. If they are exposed but not implemented, then it's a driver issue. What looks more likely, however, is that VIH2 is implemented fine as well.